# Show bangla text in DB Browser for SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, character-encoding, android-sqlite

I have a appData.db file which I collected form `.apk` file.
Now when I open this file into 'DB Browser for SQLite', some fields are not showing properly. It contains [bangle text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QXkn5.jpg).

[This field working good](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QXkn5.jpg)
[This field is not working, this is actually bangla text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUGxM.jpg)

Comment: Whatever program wrote to that database used a wrong encoding.

Comment: how to retrieve the data back?How to decode? Please Help

Comment: Show the code of the program that wrote the data.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vX45cSQhIlqniMyJL_TqDCisyB3qu1Oz/view?usp=sharing

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aTWkzCDe51QCLBt6at8eEeB6OtDb8MGu/view?usp=sharing